# How to check the CPU and Memory Utilization of a container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate

Is there a way through which I can check the CPU Utilization of each of the containers for all the tasks in a service? I have `containerInsights` enabled on the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `containerInsights` enabled on the cluster, then those metrics you are asking about should be in CloudWatch. You will also see them in the Container Insights dashboard. I suggest reading the [Container Insights release announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/introducing-container-insights-for-amazon-ecs/) that shows examples of the metrics and the dashboard.